# Loop Through Column Names with Similar Structure

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a very large dataset. Of those, a small subset have the same column name with an indexing value that is numeric (unlike the post "How to extract columns with same name but different identifiers in R" where the indexing value is a string). For example

```
Q_1_1, Q_1_2, Q_1_3, ...
```

I am looking for a way to either loop through just those columns using the indices or to subset them all at once.

I have tried to use paste() to write their column names but have had no luck. See sample code below

Define Dataframe

```
df = data.frame("Q_1_1" = rep(1,5),"Q_1_2" = rep(2,5),"Q_1_3" = rep(3,5))
```

Define the Column Name Using Paste

```
cn <- as.symbol(paste("Q_1_",1, sep=""))
cn
df$cn
df$Q_1_1
```

I want `df$cn` to return the same thing as `df$Q_1_1`, but `df$cn` returns `NULL`.

Comment: `lapply(df[paste0("Q_1_", 1:3)], FUN=...)`

Comment: use `df[, cn]` syntax instead of the `$`

Comment: @RAB that is a very easy way to what I wanted. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to subset your data frame by column name, you could use dplyr for subseting all your indexed columns at once and a regex to match all column names with a certain pattern:

```
library(dplyr)

df = data.frame("Q_1_1" = rep(1,5),"Q_1_2" = rep(2,5),"Q_1_3" = rep(3,5), "A_1" = rep(4,5))

newdf <- df %>%
  dplyr::select(matches("Q_[0-9]_[0-9]"))
```

the `[0-9]` in the regex matches any digit between the `_`. Depending on what variable you're trying to match you might have to change the regular expression.

The problem with your solution was that you only saved the name of your columns but did not actually assign it back to the data frame / to a column.

I hope this helps!